# Users added (via SQL trigger) from another database not showing in /OrchardLocal/Admin/Users

Tags: c#, sql, orchardcms

In our membership database we have a trigger that fires when a new user is added. This trigger writes user-related information to our Orchard database (on same server) and populates the following tables correctly:

- `Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord`
- `Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord`
- `Orchard_Users_UserPartRecord`

The trigger does not populate `Orchard_Roles_UserRolesPartRecord` but to be sure this wasn't the issue after the trigger had fired I added the inserted record's Id to `Orchard_Roles_UserRolesPartRecord` and assigned a role - the problem persisted.

**The problem**

When I log in as an admin user and go to the `Users` page, none of the users added via the trigger are showing up. For example, if there was 1 admin user and 1 user added via the trigger, on the `Users` page I would just see the admin user, *however*, the label on the page would read 'Showing 1 - 2 of 2 users'. So it appears that when fetching users something is not satisfied and the user added via the trigger is not being added to view model.

I have stepped through the code on the `AdminController`,

```
var users = Services.Query<UserPart, UserPartRecord>();
```

`users` object will contain 2 users as above. When this line is hit:

```
var results = users.Slice(pager.GetStartIndex(), pager.PageSize).ToList();
```

`results` object will only have 1 user, the admin user. I'm guessing that I'm missing an entry in some table. To be sure I created a new user in Orchard and inspected the generated SQL in SQL Server profiler and from what I can see no other tables need to be populated, however it seems that this is the case. Based on what I've said , can you identify anything I'm missing?

*Note:*
I have also used the import/export module to export users and for the two user records in question following are results (where orchard_test is user added via trigger):

```
  <Data>
    <User Id="/User.UserName=admin" Status="Published">
      <UserPart Email="" EmailStatus="Approved" HashAlgorithm="SHA1" NormalizedUserName="admin" Password="H0+uhIHB0dI2QSPETgqFM9dyRV4=" PasswordFormat="Hashed" PasswordSalt="H4jlZb9da7SJQj6hyQnxBA==" RegistrationStatus="Approved" UserName="admin" />
      <UserRolesPart Roles="" />
    </User>
    <User Id="/User.UserName=orchard_test" Status="Published">
      <UserPart Email="orchard_test@test.com" EmailStatus="Approved" HashAlgorithm="SHA1" NormalizedUserName="orchard_test" Password="sbCvRgQj8cRlc7YMAiW17fhTQlfXhZWHoaWyK40/DSY=" PasswordFormat="Hashed" PasswordSalt="PQSlEKDdfcbi04EpyKXfqQ==" RegistrationStatus="Approved" UserName="orchard_test" />
      <UserRolesPart Roles="" />
    </User>
  </Data>
```

Comment: Have you checked if the user has Published = 1 and Latest = 1 on Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord. Why aren't you using Orchard services, ie on a background task to import the users from the db to Orchard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE: While this did resolve the issue, it is not the recommended approach as @Bertrand pointed out.**

The problem was Orchard_Users_UserPartRecord.Id not having same value as Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord.Id and this was caused by an incorrect hierarchy of inserts in the trigger.

The correct sequence in the trigger (or any scripted insert) is:

1. Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord
2. Orchard_Users_UserPartRecord
3. Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord

Comment: I'd really recommend you stay away from direct database manipulation and use the relevant APIs instead.

Comment: This will have to do for now unfortunately. Not my call.